# How do you install a USB CD Rom drive?

Tags: 10.04, usb, cd-drive

I recently purchased a USB CD ROM drive, but I don't know how to get it to work with my computer which runs Ubuntu 10.04.

[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00303H908/ref=oss_product](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00303H908)

When I issue the **lsusb** command, it shows up as:

```
Bus 002 Device 016: ID 05e3:0701 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB 2.0 IDE Adapter
```

The computer doesn't recognize it automatically. How can I get this drive to show up as an actual drive on my computer? If this particular drive can't handle Linux, can you recommended one which can and provide a link to it so I can purchase it? Thanks!

**Update:** I was asked by *Scaine* to run a command and report back with the output:

```
joe@joe-laptop:~$ tail -f /var/log/kern.log
Dec 29 12:51:35 joe-laptop kernel: [103190.551437] sr 7:0:0:0: [sr1] Add. Sense: Illegal mode for this track
Dec 29 12:51:35 joe-laptop kernel: [103190.551446] sr 7:0:0:0: [sr1] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00
Dec 29 12:51:35 joe-laptop kernel: [103190.551463] end_request: I/O error, dev sr1, sector 0
Dec 29 12:51:35 joe-laptop kernel: [103190.877542] sr 7:0:0:0: [sr1] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
Dec 29 12:51:35 joe-laptop kernel: [103190.877551] sr 7:0:0:0: [sr1] Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
Dec 29 12:51:35 joe-laptop kernel: [103190.877559] Info fld=0x0, ILI
Dec 29 12:51:35 joe-laptop kernel: [103190.877562] sr 7:0:0:0: [sr1] Add. Sense: Illegal mode for this track
Dec 29 12:51:35 joe-laptop kernel: [103190.877572] sr 7:0:0:0: [sr1] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00
Dec 29 12:51:35 joe-laptop kernel: [103190.877588] end_request: I/O error, dev sr1, sector 0
Dec 29 13:08:46 joe-laptop kernel: [104221.558911] usb 2-2.2: USB disconnect, address 16
```

Then when I plugged the drive back into the computer, I got:

```
Dec 29 13:10:29 joe-laptop kernel: [104324.668320] usb 2-2.2: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 17
Dec 29 13:10:29 joe-laptop kernel: [104324.761702] usb 2-2.2: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
Dec 29 13:10:29 joe-laptop kernel: [104324.762700] scsi8 : SCSI emulation for USB Mass Storage devices
Dec 29 13:10:29 joe-laptop kernel: [104324.762935] usb-storage: device found at 17
Dec 29 13:10:29 joe-laptop kernel: [104324.762938] usb-storage: waiting for device to settle before scanning
Dec 29 13:10:34 joe-laptop kernel: [104329.760521] usb-storage: device scan complete
Dec 29 13:10:34 joe-laptop kernel: [104329.761344] scsi 8:0:0:0: CD-ROM            TEAC     CD-224E          1.7A PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
Dec 29 13:10:34 joe-laptop kernel: [104329.767425] sr1: scsi3-mmc drive: 24x/24x cd/rw xa/form2 cdda tray
Dec 29 13:10:34 joe-laptop kernel: [104329.767612] sr 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr1
Dec 29 13:10:34 joe-laptop kernel: [104329.767720] sr 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 5
Dec 29 13:10:34 joe-laptop kernel: [104330.141060] sr 8:0:0:0: [sr1] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
Dec 29 13:10:34 joe-laptop kernel: [104330.141069] sr 8:0:0:0: [sr1] Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
Dec 29 13:10:34 joe-laptop kernel: [104330.141077] Info fld=0x0, ILI
Dec 29 13:10:34 joe-laptop kernel: [104330.141081] sr 8:0:0:0: [sr1] Add. Sense: Illegal mode for this track
Dec 29 13:10:34 joe-laptop kernel: [104330.141090] sr 8:0:0:0: [sr1] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00
Dec 29 13:10:34 joe-laptop kernel: [104330.141106] end_request: I/O error, dev sr1, sector 0
Dec 29 13:10:34 joe-laptop kernel: [104330.141113] __ratelimit: 18 callbacks suppressed
```

There was more output than this (the number of lines started growing after the drive was plugged back in, and kept growing), but this is the first few lines.

Comment: Might be wrong but I think that your lsusb output might only be for the host controller.  Try unplugging your CD-ROM, open a terminal and type "tail -f /var/log/kern.log", then plug the CD-ROM back in again.  Post the output in your question to help others troubletshoot the problem.

Comment: Another (possibly stupid) suggestion, based on the "track" errors - can you try another CD in the CD-ROM?  Also, even without a CD in the drive, you should still be able to see the CD-ROM if you open a nautilus window, then choose the "Go" menu and select "Computer".

Answer (score 2):

looks like you're suffering from this bug:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/udev/+bug/646293

This problem is reportedly fixed in Natty, but there have been no suggestions about how to fix it properly for Maverick. I'll update this answer when I know more.

Answer (score 1):

Well in 10.10 (Did not test with 10.04 but it is most probably will work the same way). Just connect the USB CDROM Drive. Then start any burning software like Brasero or K3B. They will recognize the burner right away. No need to do anything else. But since there are still several External devices that do not yet work 100% then i will answer the alternative for you.

You have for example this one: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16827135206

Which works with 10.04 and higher. In the feedback you can see somebody already boot from it and installed ubuntu from it.

You also have this one [http://www.amazon.com/Samsung-External-Optical-SE-S084C-RSBN/dp/B002C1BBU8/?tag=klnprk-20](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002C1BBU8) that is known to be compatible with Ubuntu.

Anyway it all boils down to the company making the external unit and how fond they are of linux VS if linux has support for that device.

Here -> https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupport is a small list of hardware supported by Ubuntu

Another place where i have uploaded several info is here: http://linuxhcl.com/ where you can look for a specific device. Also here: http://hardware4linux.info/ you can do the same thing but has a much bigger database.

Anyway after all that, check either in the ubuntu forum for a device you want to buy or in the comments of that device in the place you are buying. More than likely somebody already tested this in ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you! This will be helpful in finding a drive which works

Answer (score -2):

If it doesn't work as you plug it in, it's likely that its not supported. 
[http://www.amazon.com/External-Slim-CD-ROM-Drive-Black/dp/B000YQSKPM?tag=dudugo-20](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000YQSKPM) This one apparently works on Ubuntu.